# Cannot build angleproject due to context's hWnd not supporting window property

Tags: directx

The stammen/angleproject here: https://github.com/stammen contains some samples to allow testing of the OpenGL/ES 'bridge' to directx.  I've tried compiling (both VS2012 and VS2013 sln files with VS2013 Ultimate) and find that I get the following error:

Asteroids.cpp ln 113: error C2039: 'window' : is not a member of 'Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr'

The line in question is:

```
m_esContext.hWnd.window = CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread();
```

I've tried replacing the line with:

```
auto w = CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread();
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ICoreWindowInterop> interop;
reinterpret_cast<IUnknown *>(w)->QueryInterface(interop.GetAddressOf());    
HWND hWnd = NULL;
interop->get_WindowHandle(&hWnd);
m_esContext.hWnd = hWnd;
```

...which gives me the following error in client.h at compilation:

```
cannot convert from 'HWND__ *' to 'IUnknown *'
```

Any ideas anyone?  Stammen, if you're out there...  help...  please! :)

Comment: Dale Stammen was kind enough to update the Asteroid sample today so that it now works.  Thanks to him for being so fast at responding. He points out, however, that the Asteroids sample is no longer being maintained.

Comment: How do I close this question?